# Create a UNION query that identifies which table the unique data came from

Tags: sql, ms-access, unique, union

I have two tables with data.  Both tables have a `CUSTOMER_ID` column (which is numeric).  I am trying to get a list of all the unique values for `CUSTOMER_ID` *and* know whether or not the `CUSTOMER_ID` exists in both tables or just one (and which one).

I can easily get a list of the unique `CUSTOMER_ID`:

```
SELECT tblOne.CUSTOMER_ID
FROM tblOne.CUSTOMER_ID
UNION
SELECT tblTwo.CUSTOMER_ID
FROM tblTwo.CUSTOMER_ID
```

I can't do just add an identifier column to the `SELECT` statemtn (like: `SELECT tblOne.CUSTOMER_ID, "Table1" AS DataSource`) because then the records wouldn't be unique and it will get both sets of data.

I feel I need to add it somewhere else in this query but am not sure how.

#### Edit for clarity:

For the union query output I need an additional column that can tell me if the unique value I am seeing exists in: (1) *both* tables, (2) table one, or (3) table two.

Comment: Does access support derived tables?  select * from (subquery code) x

Comment: the problem is the "and which one" phrase... this rises the difficulty :)

Comment: @Apostolos - yes, I need to have three possible values for this added `DataSource` column: 'both', 'tblOne', 'tblTwo'.  Or it could be BLANK then 'tblOne' and 'tblTwo'.  I just need to know which CUSTOMER_IDs are in both versus and if not, where they are.

Comment: nevermind i deleted my answer because i used full outer join, not supported in ms-access

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the CUSTOMER_ID appears in both tables then we'll have to arbitrarily pick which table to call the source. The following query uses "tblOne" as the [SourceTable] in that case:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_ID,
    MIN(Source) AS SourceTable,
    COUNT(*) AS TableCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            CUSTOMER_ID, 
            "tblOne" AS Source
        FROM tblOne
    UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT
            CUSTOMER_ID,
            "tblTwo" AS Source
        FROM tblTwo
    )
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: The subquery needs an alias.  Hopefully access supports this construct.

Comment: @Dan Yes, that query works in Access. I tested it before posting it.

Comment: @GordThompson - thanks! learned something new about SELECT and FROM.  However: I do need to know if the CUSTOMER_ID appears in *both* or just *one* of the tables.  I think this method wouldn't allow me to distinguish ... if I can't do it with a query I can write some VBA to do it ... I just thought a query would be faster and easier.

Comment: @thornomad If the CUSTOMER_ID appears in both tables then [TableCount] will be 2, otherwise it will be 1.

Comment: @thornomad You're welcome. BTW, I tweaked the query slightly by adding DISTINCT to the subquery components. That will ensure consistent results even if there are duplicate CUSTOMER_ID values in either of the two tables.

Comment: @GordThompson great answer - but am i understanding correctly? The middle column: Min(source) will read tell you which table the row is coming from: if it is coming from the source table then it will read 0, and if it is coming from the tableTwo, then it will read 1? Is this correct?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon No, it will read 'tblOne' or 'tblTwo' because the `Source` column in the subquery is text.

Comment: @GordThompson excellent Gord - your knowledge and answer is amazing and is changing the world. i know stackoverflow dislikes comments like this one, but yeah it's gotta be made.

Answer (score 3):

Gord Thompson's answer is correct.  But, it is not necessary to do a distinct in the subqueries.  And, you can return a single column with the information you are looking for:

```
select customer_id,
       iif(min(which) = max(which), min(which), "both") as DataSource
from (select customer_id, "tblone" as which
      from tblOne
      UNION ALL
      select customer_id, "tbltwo" as which
      from tblTwo
     ) t
group by customer_id
```

Comment: Yes, the DISTINCT in the subqueries is not absolutely necessary. However, as I noted in the comments to my answer, I added them in case there were duplicate CUSTOMER_ID values in either of the tables. Specifically, two such values in [tblOne] and no such values in [tblTwo] would give misleading results: it would look like CUSTOMER_ID appeared in both tables when really it didn't. BTW, nice touch with the `IIf(Min()=Max()...`.

Comment: @GordThompson . . . In your version of the query, you need `distinct` because you are using `count(*)` in the outer query.  If you used `count(distinct)` in the outer query, then it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: `count(distinct)` is not supported in Access SQL.

Answer (score 2):

We could add an identifier column with the integer data type and then do an outer query:

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER_ID,
sum(Table)

FROM 
(
SELECT 
  DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID, 
  1 AS Table
FROM tblOne
UNION
SELECT 
  DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID,
  2 AS Table
FROM tblTwo
)
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID`
```

So if the "sum is 1" then it comes from tablOne and if it is 2 then it comes from tableTwo an if it is 3 then it exists in both

If you want to add a 3rd table in the union then give it a value of 4 so that you should have a unique sum for each combination